# udp server on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, udp

I'm trying to send some up sensor data from arduino to my iPhone and i found here (http://www.benripley.com/development/ios/udp-server-on-iphone/) and I run it with some small mods to make it compile on a viewController I display the data and everything works perfectly. But when I leave the view and go back, probably because it tries to start the server again, the app crashes. i tried to move the code to the appDelegate to start the server on launch but the app crashes on launch. even if I try only to start the server on launch and start reading by the time I enter the view and the same thing happens. Any idea?

here is the code:

```
    #include < sys/socket.h >

    #include < arpa/inet.h >

    #include < errno.h >

    #define UDP 17

   typedef struct sockaddr_in sockaddr_in;


    - (void)startServer {

        NSLog(@"UDP Server started...");

        sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

        struct sockaddr_in sa;



        memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));

        sa.sin_family = AF_INET;

        sa.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        sa.sin_port = htons(5009);

        // bind the socket to our address

        if (-1 == bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(struct sockaddr)))

        {

            perror("error bind failed");

            close(sock);

            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        }

        for (;;)

        {

            recsize = recvfrom(sock,
                               (void *)buffer,
                               1024,
                               0,
                               (struct sockaddr *)&sa,
                               &fromlen);

            if (recsize < 0)
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));

            msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", buffer];

            NSLog(msg);

        }
    }
```

and the actual call is this:

```
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startServer)
                                 toTarget:self
                               withObject:nil];
```

Comment: What is the crash message?

Comment: on main.m gives me a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT on the main line.

Comment: You should set an exception breakpoint to find the actual line

Comment: with the breakpoint it gives me an error as soon as i start the server on the appDelegate:
 -[AppDelegate startServer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c505d70

Comment: AppDelegate would (or should) be your AppDelegate class (since it starts with an upper case A) - so, unless startServer is a class method (has a + rather than a - in the method declaration) this is your problem.  You probably want `[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate startServer];` or even `[self startServer];` if you are in the app delegate

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work but for some reason now it works! probably it was messed up yesterday! thanks!